# How to set system properties in ignite 2.15

Tags: ignite

I have already upgrade ignite to 2.15 version. In this latest version, we can process atomic atomic cache in transaction, so please kindly help to set this system properties in ignite IGNITE_ALLOW_ATOMIC_OPS_IN_TX = true

Answer (score 1):

Either set `JVM_OPTS`:

```
export JVM_OPTS=-DIGNITE_ALLOW_ATOMIC_OPS_IN_TX=true
ignite.sh
```

Or:

```
ignite.sh -J-DIGNITE_ALLOW_ATOMIC_OPS_IN_TX=true
```